# Binding row selection to ViewModel's property

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

This should be simple but am stuck with it. If my `DataGrid` is bound to a collection (say a `DataTable`) and one of the public properties of the items (DataRows) is named `IsHighlighted`, can I bind my DataGrid's rows `IsSelected` status to this property, so that changing the property value in the table would reflect in the UI by selecting/unselecting corresponding DataGrid rows?

Comment: Check with Snoop, to know the DataContext of row and Bind with corresponding source..

Comment: @Sankarann: `for(int i=0; i< 100; i++) Comments.Append("Thanks");`

Comment: @Sankarann: Snoop is one gem of a tool. I figured this out. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out through Snoop. The `DataContext` of a `DataGridRow` (when the `DataGrid` is bound to a `DataTable`) is `DataRowView` and not `DataRow`. The problem was that `IsHighlighted` was a public property added thru the `DataRow`'s partial class and therefore didn't make its way to the `DataRowView`. I have now added an explicit column to the `DataTable` through the DataSet designer and everything is working fine. Hope it helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
         <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsHighlighted}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Your solution is in fact correct. I was wrong on the other end. See my answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Above snippet seems to be correct with a slight modification.
Try this

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsHighlighted, Mode="TwoWay"}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I am assuming you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your model class.

Comment: Your solution is in fact correct. I was wrong on the other end. See my answer. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Not sure if this worked the time you wrote that, but currently ```Mode="TwoWay"``` should be  ```Mode='TwoWay'``` or even ```Mode=TwoWay```. Else VS (2019) will not understand.